# How does the locale setting change affect on upgrading PostgreSQL server on Azure?

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

I am going to upgrade PostgreSQL server from "Single Server" to "Flexible Server"(version 13) due to some business requirements. According to [the Azure's doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-compare-single-server-flexible-server), the Flexible Server uses "  en_US.utf8" while the Single Server does "English_United States.1252". How does this affect? [The Postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/charset.html#:%7E:text=The%20LC_COLLATE%20and%20LC_CTYPE%20variables,that%20are%20seen%20by%20initdb.) says *"The LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE variables affect the sort order of indexes"*. If this is the case, I need to rebuild the indexes. I am wondering what else needs to be done for successful migration. I appreciate any advice on this. Thanks.

I would like to know what would be the standard procedure when the locale setting is changed.

Comment: According to the Azure documentation, the Flexible Server uses "en_US.utf8" while the Single Server does "English_United States.1252"[2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-major-version-upgrade.md). The Postgres documentation states that "The LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE variables affect the sort order of indexes"[1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/synapse-analytics/sql/reference-collation-types.md). Therefore, you may need to rebuild the indexes.

Comment: In addition, you may need to perform a dry run of the in-place major version upgrade in a non-production environment before upgrading the production server[2]. This allows you to identify any application incompatibilities and validate that the upgrade completes successfully before upgrading the production environment. You can perform a Point-In-Time Recovery (PITR) of your production server and test the upgrade in the non-production environment[2]. Addressing these issues before the production upgrade minimizes downtime and ensures a smooth upgrade process.

Comment: do you require any another information about the question let me now?

Comment: @Sampath 
Thank you so much for the details.

Comment: I am not sure why I cannot find a button to accept your answer....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@Sampath @Masakorelab**, Posting it as Answer

According to the Azure documentation, the Flexible Server uses **“en_US.utf8”** while the Single Server does "English_United States.1252"[2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-major-version-upgrade.md). The Postgres documentation states that "The LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE variables affect the sort order of indexes"[1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/synapse-analytics/sql/reference-collation-types.md). Therefore, you may need to rebuild the indexes.

[image]

In addition, you may need to perform a dry run of the in-place major version upgrade in a non-production environment before upgrading the production server. This allows you to identify any application incompatibilities and validate that the upgrade completes successfully before upgrading the production environment. You can perform a Point-In-Time Recovery (PITR) of your production server and test the upgrade in the non-production environment. Addressing these issues before the production upgrade minimizes downtime and ensures a smooth upgrade process